# Live Database for Marquee

Tags: javascript, c#, html, json

I'm am in need of some assistance creating a live graph that will update in ms. I have App in C# that captures the Idle timer/CPU/Memory/etc on several PC's. I would like to send that information to a website and update a graph in a real time manner.

Ultimately I would like to live stream a JSON file to the main server(not sure how to go about that)

Now I use SQL to update but there is some latency between the constant update and select query.

My other thought is to create an HTML/Web server and pass the JSON directly through a data stream. think this may be overkill as each PC would have to run the Web Server.

I believe there is a simple way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: There isn't really a question here. Does "Now I use SQL to update" mean that you run some kind of update query from the client on the server? How "real time" does it need to be? What are the constraints on the client and server? Not enough detail.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I guess the question is how to read and write at the same time to some sort of data stream to update a graph on a website. 
As far as real time 2ms - 500ms would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone looking at this for an answer I was able to resolve this by opening a data stream using HTTPRequest to query the data. It is surprisingly low overhead.